Что это за бот, который по 1000 url адресов обход за час, грубо
Записываю url адреса в таблицу, которые отдают страницы 404...
Вижу что какой то ли бот, то ли что другое. В общем он заходит на сайт, на url которых никогда не было. То файлы запрашивает, то еще что, хаотично.
user_agent показывает его как
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Что это и что в таких случаях лучше предпринять?
За пол часа открыл около 200 - 500 страниц. Такое впечатление, что у него хаотичный набор слов и по каждой фразе открывает мой сайт...
То инстаграм, то файлы вор экспресса ищет, то файлы php пытается скачать. В общем не предсказуемое того чего он пытается сделать...
Различные zip архивы ищет...

Ну, какой-то бот. По такому user agent невозможно ничего сказать, его можно вообще любой прописать. Если сайт у вас не падает от его деятельности - в принципе можно ничего не делать. Можно пробовать банить по ip при большом количестве 404 ошибок, но это ненадежно, на одном ip может много пользователей сидеть теоретически.

Боты постоянно обходят сайты в поисках типичных уязввимостей. Вас тоже щупают. Бот ищет незащищенные админки для всех популярных фреймворков.
